# Google colab uploading files to Filebin as application/octet-stream

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mime-types, octet-stream

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to upload a file from Google Colab to Filebin using Python code. The upload process appears to proceed smoothly, but upon arrival, the file is identified as "application/octet-stream." Consequently, when attempting to use the downloaded file, problems arise, despite its seemingly correct size and having been renamed appropriately. The file type in question is a 'ckpt' file, although it appears that other file types encounter similar issues under the circumstances I've described.

Oddly, when I upload the same file directly from my personal computer, it displays the correct file type. Subsequently, after downloading, the file functions as expected on other devices and within Colab. I'm puzzled by this discrepancy and uncertain as to what might be causing this problem.

This is the code I used.

````
import requests

file_path = 'colab-path-file'  # Replace this with the path to your file
filebin_bin_url = 'filebin-upload-link'  # Replace this with your Filebin bin URL

# Filebin API endpoint for file uploads (using the bin URL)
filebin_api = f'{filebin_bin_url}/files'

# Create a file object
file_data = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}

# Headers
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}

# Make a POST request to upload the file
response = requests.post(filebin_api, files=file_data, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("File uploaded successfully to Filebin.")
    print("Filebin URL:", response.json().get('url'))
else:
    print("File upload failed. Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Error message:", response.text) 
    ```
````

Comment: some system needs file extension to recognize type of file but other need `header` - `Content-type`